# how to create a git repo with subfolders that contain files?

Tags: github

when pushing my local repo (which is composed of multiple subfolders that contain my files) to github, the names of the folders are listed on the github repo but they aren't designated as folders/don't have any files in them that I can access... How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your subfolder (that you are pushing) include a `.git/` in them.

That would make them nested git repo (or even [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), if you have a .gitmodule in your main repo)

As such, their **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) would be shown on GitHub as an empty gray folder.