# Some files and folders from my Xcode project are not being pushed to remote repository

Tags: ios, xcode, git, repository, bitbucket

I had 3 separate Xcode projects. All 3 were pushed to individual remote repos on bitbucket. I decided to combine these 3 projects, so I dragged some files and folders from 2 projects into the main one. Now, when I push to the remote repo, the files & folders that i dragged into the main project do not show up on bitbucket, but they are in the project folder on my computer and the app works fine. Any ideas why these new files/folders aren't showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their content is not showing up because, when you dragged those project folder, you also included their .git subfolders.

That will make those folder **nested git repositories**, in which case the parent repo will only record the [tree SHA1 (a gitlink)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667881/6309), and not their content.

If you don't care about the history of those two repos, first remove their .git, then drag, add, commit and push.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So how do I resolve this issue? ...How do I remove those .git subfolders. I don't see them in my project directory. Do I delete the other remote repos?

Comment: @c0nman Those subfolders `.git/` are generally "hidden" (https://www.lifewire.com/display-hidden-files-in-os-x-153332)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you whatever file you are dragging in your main project. First copy it in your main project local disc folder, and then drag to your main Xcode project.

It should works