# undo submodule and make it a directory to a github repository

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-add

I cloned a repository from github, and I would like to make it a directory in an other github repository. Though it is considered as a submodule (and I don't want it to be a submodule, but a directory). 
In this directory i have some script that I would like to push on my github repository.

When i do : `git status` i get this error message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   my_directory (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I tried to do `git add .` ; `git add my_directory` and to commit it, but it's not working neither.

I don't find any .gitignore or .gitmodules...

**edit :**

finally i find how to do what i want, i had to delete the .git that was in my directory. Though it was an invisible file...
Once this was done, i just had to do `git commit -a` and then `git push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that directory has a `.git/` subfolder in it, it will act as a nested git repository.

If you add that folder, you actually are adding only the [tree SHA1 (gitlink)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667881/6309) to your repo, not the folder content.

To undo that:

```
git rm --cached my_directory
```

(very important: no trailing slash: you want to delete the entry, not the folder content)

If you don't care about the history of the content, delete `my_directory/.git`

Then you can add, commit and push as usual: that folder will be a regular folder.

Comment: ok thanks, but i already did this without sucess. Finally i had to delete the .git in my directory that i wasn't able to see it...

Comment: If you delete the.git of your subfolder, and do a git rm --cached as instructed, then you will be able to add that subfolder content.